# Initial letters missing while using type() in Cypress

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, cypress

**Scenario:**

```html
<tr>
  <td id="type1">
    <div><span></span></div>
  </td>
  <td id="type2">
    <div><span></span></div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

```js
cy.get('#type1').type('Abcd') // skips the initial letters ie,   
                              // it actually types 'bcd' or 'cd'
```

There's an issue here [Missing letters when using type #3817](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/3817). I can see this issue is resolved, but I'm still facing this issue. Any workarounds?

Comment: Small workaround that might help - cy.get('#type1').click().type('Abcd')

Comment: or cy.get('#type1').focus().type('Abcd') would also do the job

Answer (score 6):

This question leaves out some vital bits that I would like to clear up.

If you try out the click-trick on that HTML snippet, you will come a cropper.

This is the error

> cy.type() failed because it requires a valid **typeable element.**
>
> A typeable element matches one of the following selectors:
>
> ```js
> a[href]  
> area[href]  
> input  
> select  
> textarea  
> button  
> iframe  
> [tabindex]  
> [contenteditable]
> ```

The last two are the only options for this particular HMTL, so you could make it work like this:

```js
cy.get('#type1')
  .invoke('attr', 'contenteditable')   // make it editable
  .type('Abcd')

  .should('contain', 'Abcd')           // confirm it has the text

  .invoke('removeAttr', 'contenteditable')     // optionally remove the attribute
  .should('not.have.attr', 'contenteditable')
```